# Dependencies in pom file - how does it work

Tags: java, eclipse, pom.xml

I see some java programming examples on the internet which require me to use non-standard api's. So, the authors mentioned that a pom file is needed. I need to understand what is the purpose of this file and how does it get bound/"binded" to a java project.

When I add a non-standard jar to my project's build path in eclipse, is it the same as creating a pom file, doing something "magical" with it and then "binding" it to my project?
Or is it something else ?

Comment: More information can be found here http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html

Comment: @PradeepSimha - I am reading that link now to know more about pom files. But, I never even touched maven and i doubt if there is any need to touch it as long as eclipse handles the stuff for me. So, can you tell me if "add jar to build path" == 'create a pom file and do something with it' ?

Comment: _"add jar to build path" == 'create a pom file and do something with it' ?_ no that is not true. By adding jar to build path you are just saying to eclipse where to look for jar files that's it.

Comment: @PradeepSimha - What role does pom file play inside eclipse ?

Comment: See her http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1677994/what-is-the-significance-of-the-pom-file-that-maven-places-in-a-jar-file-is-it

Comment: @PradeepSimha - I saw that it is metadata for a jar. But, why would the author mention pom and code in the pom for a simple hello world like example?

Comment: Just to illustrate how it works they use hello world, instead of using very complicated example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The pom file is the main artifact of Maven, which is a build tool. Maven has many uses, but the most common is dependency management (build management is also a core feature). The way it works is that it allows you to define dependencies to external libraries that your project needs, and when you use Maven to build your project it will fetch these libraries from the web (external repositories) and add them to your built project. So it's an automatic handling of dependencies.

So if you for instance you want to include Spring in your Maven project, you edit your pom.xml and add

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</group>
    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.3.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Where the groupId and artifactId is an unique identifier of the library you want to include, and version to select the right jar-file. Now, when the project is built with Maven (`mvn install`), it will try to fetch jar from the web and add it to the classpath of your built project.

Maven might be a bit hard to get started with, since there are so many options, but for learning Maven I would recommend starting with the build cycle and dependency management, and then move on to more advanced topics when you have a good understanding on how these things work.