# Maven - Remove Dependency from a Jar

Tags: eclipse, maven, jar, dependencies

I'm using a Jar file as an dependency in my application's pom.xml. Unfortunately there is a pom.xml and pom.properties files in this jar and my maven application is trying to download an extra artifact present in these files.

Can you please let me know how to exclude these files or stop looking for an extra artifact.

Example: i'm adding abc.jar

```
<dependency>
<groupId>xyz</groupId>
<artifactId>abc</artifactId>
<version>1</version>
</dependency>
```

Now "abc.jar" has it's own pom.xml where an artifact is present as below

```
<parent>
<groupId>DEFGH</groupId>
<artifactId>NewArtifact</artifactId>
<version>1</version>
</parent>
```

Note : I tried with "exclusions" under "dependency" tag but of no use.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this snippet:

```
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.squirrelframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>squirrel-foundation</artifactId>
    <version>0.3.2</version>
    <!-- explicitly disable squirrel-foundation dependency because it messes up project logging backend configuration -->
    <exclusions>
      <exclusion>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
      <exclusion>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
  </dependency>
```

In this snippet I explicitly drop the dependencies on log4j and slf4j-log4j12 come with the `squirrel-foundation` package.

If you can control the building process of the dependent jar you can use [this recipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1677994/what-is-the-significance-of-the-pom-file-that-maven-places-in-a-jar-file-is-it) to completely exclude pom.xml and pom.properties from the jar, but I doubt it's a good solution. It would be more correct to handle extra dependencies some other way/

Comment: is there any other way to exclude these files? not sure what hapnd it's not working in my case.